# TFTP/PXE with the foreman

Tags: pxe-boot, tftp

I'm having trouble getting PXE working with the foreman. It dl's pxelinux.0 fine, find the correct pxelinux.cfg for the mac address and then tried to download the kernel. Then we have a failure:

Could not find kernel image: boot/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-vmlinuz
boot:

I can download the file manually from another box via TFTP.

The errors logs look like this:

http://pastebin.com/Mps4TDM2

what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the `/srv/tftp/boot` directory on your Foreman host. Is the `CentOS-6.3-x86_64-vmlinuz` (and/or `CentOS-6.3-x86_64-initrd.img`) file zero size? (i.e. empty)